# How does the training data look like in Yolo model

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I'm trying to figure out how to create YOLOv1 model from scratch but I can't figure out how the training data should look like. I suspect training labels (ground truth) looks like a matrix with (7, 7, 5*2 + 10) where

- 7x7 stands for the prediction grid
- 5 is object location and confidence (always equal to 1); x,y - known box center; h,v - box height and width
- *2 is because there should be horizontal and vertical box for each cell
- 10 - is one-hot encoding for a class present in this position

what I don't understand is

- whether to put confidence==1 to both horizontal and vertical bounding boxes?
- whether x and y should be coordinates in the original (resized for the input) image?

...or maybe I'm completely off with my whole understanding. Does somebody have experience with YOLO?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/experiencor/basic-yolo-keras/blob/master/preprocessing.py#L141-L229) implementation?

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed a very clean implementation with some difference to the original. He used additional dimension to separate one-hot vector from box+confidence, so the final batch y matrix has following dimensions `[b_size, grid_h, grid_w, classes, 5]`. Otherwise, I was close, except the one-hot is repeated for every box. Also  if somebody else will be coming across this comment, check out one of the older versions of the code with only a proof-of-concept, it is much simplier: https://github.com/experiencor/basic-yolo-keras/tree/9936e14491713aa4d83458ecc738b197a5e47f6f